# How to send a Notification for particular Android device by unique id via GCM by Windows Azure?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, azure-mobile-services

I have done a simple Broadcasting the notification to android device using azure mobile service, I have received all the notifications.

But how to send a notification to particular device by using unique id like MAC-id or IMEI No(Any unique id from device).I have seen the 
following link [Here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-android-breaking-news/) but it used some TAG to get notification. But I didn't get the notification.

**My client code is**

```
private void registerForNotification() {
        try {
            NotificationsManager.handleNotifications(this, SENDER_ID, ClientNotificationHandler.class);
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://notifischeduler-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedKey";
            hub = new NotificationHub("notifischeduler", connectionString, this);
            if(Constant.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Hub Details >>> "+hub.getConnectionString()+"   HUB Path >> "+hub.getNotificationHubPath());
            registerWithNotificationHubs();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void registerWithNotificationHubs() {
        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                try {
                    hub.unregister();
                    String regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    String[] devArray = {"ANDROIDMOBILE2".trim()};
                    if(Constant.DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG,"HuB RegID  "+regid);
                    hub.register(regid,devArray);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return e;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

In the `devArray` I need to pass the Unique Identification. How to achieve this?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCM Registration ID is the unique ID to identify a Android Device...

String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

Answer (score 0):

GCM Registration ID is the unique ID to identify any Android Device

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
regId = getRegistrationId(context);
```

and then send a Notification to `regId` (a unique Android device).